# How to visit the source code block of the noweb-ref at point?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

If my cursor is on `<<globals>>`, how can I open the org-src block similar to `org-open-at-point`.

```
#+begin_src shell :noweb yes :tangle ~/file.txt
<<globals>>
<<aliases>>
#+end_src
```

Comment: Note that more than one block can be given the same noweb-ref if you want it to only be one block the use the NAME property

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you `name` your source blocks with `#+name: foo` e.g.:

```
#+name: globals
#+begin_src elisp
globals
#+end_src

#+name: aliases
#+begin_src elisp
aliases
#+end_src

#+name: bar
#+begin_src shell :noweb yes :tangle ~/file.txt
<<globals>>
<<aliases>>
#+end_src
```

You can then use `org-babel-goto-named-source-block`, perhaps in a wrapper to implement the `-at-point` functionality, although that seems to work fine out of the box: the default choice is the name that you are currently on.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out `org-babel-goto-named-source-block`.

Answer (score 1):

@NickD's answer is more standards compliant given that it utilizes orgmode's internal mechanism. Meanwhile, I had also put together a function that will visit the `noweb-ref` without the necessity of naming the src block.

```lisp
(defun mb/try-open-noweb-at-point ()
  "Try to visit the noweb-ref source at point."
  (interactive)
  (let ((thing (thing-at-point 'symbol 't))
        (found nil))
    (catch 'foo
      (org-babel-map-src-blocks nil
        (if-let* ((args (nth 2 (org-babel-get-src-block-info t)))
                  (noweb-ref (alist-get :noweb-ref args)))
            (when (equal thing noweb-ref)
              (org-show-set-visibility 'minimal)
              (with-current-buffer (buffer-name)
                (goto-char beg-body)
                (throw 'foo (setq found t)))
              t))))
    (if (equal found nil)
        (message "not found"))))
```

Comment: Your solution assumes that each relevant code block is basically named with a `:noweb-ref`. That's not the purpose of the `:noweb-ref` header (see [Noweb reference syntax](https://orgmode.org/manual/Noweb-Reference-Syntax.html#Noweb-Reference-Syntax) for an example of its usage). Nevertheless, +1 for the use of `org-babel-map-src-blocks` and in particular for `beg-body` which I had forgotten about and had to look for in the doc string of the function :-)

Comment: I believe you can avoid calling `org-babel-get-src-block-info`: the header args are available inside `org-babel-map-src-blocks` as the value of `header-args` (untested).